# RFID reader shows (Authentication failed(): communication error) when scanning card

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project. In the project I am using an Arduino Uno board to take input from an RFID reader (MFRC522). With the reader I got a keychain tag and identity card tag. I am using the MFRC522 library, which I downloaded from Github. In that I tried the `dumpinfo` example code to scan a card. The reader works fine with default cards. (Keychain and identity card tag).

Now the problem is when I scan my college identity card it shows an error `"Authentication failed () :communication error"`.

Please help me. Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found answer to my question.`Default RFID tags` comes with any one of these following keys :

1. FF FF FF FF FF FF
2. A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
3. B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
4. 4D 3A 99 C3 51 DD
5. 1A 98 2C 7E 45 9A
6. D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7
7. AA BB CC DD EE FF

The above default keys is also known as `smart card keys`.To access the data in tag we need to add these keys in our source code. If the key is incorrect then data in the card cannot be accessible and throws an error message `Authentication failed () :communication error`.

Similarly my `college Identity Tag` different key is set by card seller where that key did not matched with default keys that i used in my source code. In this case when i scanned my collage identity tag with RFID reader i got an `Authentication failed () :communication error`